# What is the way to query with array condition in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore db has such a structure:

```
forms
  -- status: "IN_PROGRESS"
  -- approvalBy:   (array)
     [0]
     -- status: "current"
     -- uid: "1111"
     -- order: 10
     [1]
     -- status: "waiting"
     -- uid: "1111"
     -- order: 20
```

I want to get documents whose

1. status = "IN_PROGRESS"
2. approvalBy.status == "current"
3. approvalBy.status == "1111"

In Swift, I use something like this but it gets 0 document,

```
    let whereFields: [String: Any] = [
        "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "approvalBy": [
            "status": "current",
            "uid": "1111",
        ]
    ]

    var query: Query = Firestore.firestore().collection(collection)
        
    for (field, value) in whereFields {
        query = query.whereField(field, isEqualTo: value)
    }
        
    query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
      ....
    }
```

I also tried something like this but get 0 documents too:

```
    let whereFields: [String: Any] = [
        "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "approvalBy": [
            "array-contains-any": [
                "status": "current",
                "uid": "1111",
            ]
        ]
    ]
or
    let whereFields: [String: Any] = [
        "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "approvalBy.status": "current",
        "approvalBy.uid": "1111",
    ]
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I dont think you can query an array of objects, for a specific field. You can however query the array for an entire object:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection(collection).whereField("approvalBy", arrayContains: ["status":"current", "uid":"1111", "order":10]).whereField("status", isEqualTo: "IN_PROGRESS").getDocuments...
```

The key is querying for the exact entire object, which in swift is a dictionary, so hopefully you know the other values that are in there exactly.